# C# How to get the underlying Value for (T?) where T is ref or valueType?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to write a function that takes in T? where T is reference or value type. The function returns failure if the value is null, otherwise it returns as the Non Nullable type.

The following code will not compile.

```cs
public static Result<T> ToResult<T>(this T? nullable, Error error)
{
    if (nullable is null)
        return Result.Failure<T>(error);
    if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
        return Result.Success(Nullable.GetValueRefOrDefaultRef<T>(nullable));

    return Result.Success(nullable);
}
```

The following code will work but the type remains (`T?`)

```
    if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
        return Result.Success(nullable);
```

The only way I have be able to solve it is by using two different functions like

```cs
public static Result<T> ToResult<T>(in this T? nullable, Error error)
    where T : struct
{
    if (!nullable.HasValue)
        return Result.Failure<T>(error);

    return Result.Success<T>(nullable.Value);
}
public static Result<T> ToResult<T>(this T? obj, Error error)
    where T : class
{
    if (obj == null)
        return Result.Failure<T>(error);

    return Result.Success<T>(obj);
}
```

Is it possible to solve it using a single method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's possible, it's probably not the result you want.

Generic parameter types are inferred at the compile time, the following code:

```
int? v = 1;
var result = v.ToResult(error);
```

Will be expanded to:

```
Nullable<int> v = 1;
Result<Nullable<int>> result = ToResult(v, error);
```

So if you must use a single method, you have to explicitly specific the return type like this:

```
public static Result<U> ToResult<T, U>(T? nullable, Error error)
{
    if (nullable is null)
        return Result.Failure<U>(error);
    return Result.Success<U>(Unsafe.As<T, U>(ref nullable));
}
var result = v.ToResult<int?, int>(error);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like,  Type underlyingType = nullable.GetType(); return Result.Success(Unsafe.As<T, underlyingType>(ref nullable));   ?  Several functions build upon ToResult so making it <T,U> has a cascading effect.  https://github.com/vkhorikov/CSharpFunctionalExtensions/blob/master/CSharpFunctionalExtensions/Result/NullableExtensions.cs

Comment: The problem is no matter how hard you try to turn the tide inside the method, it won't help, when you write this code `var result = v.ToResult(error);`, the generic parameter type of the return value has been uniquely determined based on the type of `v`.